# SQLite How to get the next row, but get the first if current is last

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables.

Table of training sessions:

```
CREATE TABLE `training_session` (
`_id`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`date_time` TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`training_day_id`   INTEGER,
`duration`  INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(`training_day_id`) REFERENCES `training_program_day`(`_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Table of days of the training program:

```
CREATE TABLE `training_program_day` (
`_id`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`name`  TEXT NOT NULL,
`program_id`    INTEGER,
`number`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(`program_id`) REFERENCES `training_program`(`_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Table of training programs:

```
CREATE TABLE `training_program` (
`_id`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`name`  INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

In the table of training days, there is a column `number` that determines the order in which the training day goes in the program. I get the `number` of the last training day from the `training_session` table:

```
SELECT tpd.number
FROM training_session AS ts 
LEFT JOIN training_program_day AS tpd ON ts.training_day_id = tpd._id
WHERE ts.training_day_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ts.date_time
DESC LIMIT 1
```

I want to get data on the next training day, so I use the code above as a subquery and find a training day, whose number is 1 more.

```
SELECT 
tp.name AS program,
tpd.name AS training_day
FROM training_program_day AS tpd
LEFT JOIN training_program AS tp ON tpd.program_id = tp._id
WHERE tpd.number = 1 + (
    SELECT tpd.number
    FROM training_session AS ts 
    LEFT JOIN training_program_day AS tpd ON ts.training_day_id = tpd._id
    WHERE ts.training_day_id IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY ts.date_time
    DESC LIMIT 1)
```

This query works correctly if the day's `number` found in the subquery is not the largest in the `training_prorgam_day` table. Of course, otherwise nothing comes back. But the days in the training program must be cycled, and therefore I want to get the data for the first day in the program if the `number` found in the subquery is the largest one. But I don't know how to do this. I started to learn SQLite recently and therefore do not know all its features. I would not be surprised if you say that my request is not effective. I will be very grateful for your optimization.

For example, I have such data in the tables:

training_session
[image: training_session]

training_program_day
[image: training_program_day]

[image]

I want to get this:
[image: result]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I attached the data to the post.

Comment: Your last query returns not nothing but `shoulders`. Is this correct? Is there some `program_id` or `training_day_id` check missing?

Comment: @CL. Yes you are right. Yesterday I tested the query when only one training program was added and missed this check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery `last` is as above.
The first join in the outer query then searches for two rows, one with the next-larger number, and one with number `1`.
The `ORDER BY`/`LIMIT` then returns only the row with the largest number, i.e., the next one if it exists, or else the first one.

```
SELECT next._id, next.name, p.name
FROM (SELECT d.program_id, d.number
      FROM training_program_day AS d
      JOIN training_session AS s ON d._id = s.training_day_id
      ORDER BY s.date_time DESC
      LIMIT 1) AS last
JOIN training_program_day AS next ON next.program_id = last.program_id
                                 AND next.number IN (last.number + 1, 1)
JOIN training_program AS p ON next.program_id = p._id
ORDER BY next.number DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The query seems to be working, but I think that it can be written easier and more efficiently. Waiting for your optimization.

```
-- 4) Find the data for the day you want
SELECT tp.name AS prog_name, tpd4.name AS day_name, tpd4._id AS day_id
FROM (
  -- 3) If there is no such day, take the first day from this program
  SELECT 
  last_prog_id,
  ifnull(last_number_plus_1, 1) AS desired_number
  FROM (
    -- 2) Looking for a training day from the same program, whose number is 1 more.
    SELECT
    last_prog_id,
    tpd2.number AS last_number_plus_1
    FROM (
      -- 1) Find the training day we trained for the last time
      SELECT
      tpd1.program_id AS last_prog_id,
      tpd1.number AS last_number
      FROM training_session AS ts 
      LEFT JOIN training_program_day AS tpd1 ON ts.training_day_id = tpd1._id
      WHERE ts.training_day_id IS NOT NULL 
      ORDER BY ts.date_time DESC
      LIMIT 1
    )
    LEFT JOIN training_program_day AS tpd2
    ON last_prog_id = tpd2.program_id AND last_number + 1 = tpd2.number
  )
  LEFT JOIN training_program_day AS tpd3
  ON last_prog_id = tpd3.program_id AND last_number_plus_1 = tpd3.number
)
INNER JOIN training_program_day AS tpd4
ON last_prog_id = tpd4.program_id AND desired_number = tpd4.number
INNER JOIN training_program AS tp
ON last_prog_id = tp._id
```